How can I do a post-order traversal of a tree, when the only function I have is getChildren()?
I'm trying to collect all nodes in specific post-order traversal order. However, I'm not quite sure how to do this when my only function is getChildren(), rather than a left or right child. Here is the traversal I currently have, in Java.
Set<Node> postOrderedNodes = traverseSubAssembly(rootNode);

private static Set<Node> traverseSubAssembly(Node node) {

        Set<Node> nodes = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        nodes.add(node);

        for (Node child : node.getChildren()) {
            nodes.addAll(traverseSubAssembly(child));
        }

        return nodes;
    }


What language is this? Is HashSet an ordered set?

Why would it matter which children are left or right (or even whether it's a binary tree at all)? As long as they are returned in order, you can build your pre-order or post-order traversal from this.

The definition of post-order is to visit each node after all its children. In this case, visiting is adding the node to a list. So just implement this as a recursive method. The method first recurs to visit each child returned by get-children, then visits (adds the node to the list).  Tada! The simplest way to implement this is to return nothing from the recursive method. Maintain the result list outside the method, e.g. make the search a method in a class and the list a field.  Or you can pass a reference to the list as a parameter .

@Bergi Java, I suppose I should be using LinkedHashSet

Set<Node> postOrderedNodes = traverseSubAssembly(rootNode);

private static Set<Node> traverseSubAssembly(Node node) {
    Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<>();

    for (Node child : node.getChildren()) {
        nodes.addAll(traverseSubAssembly(child));
    }

    nodes.add(node);  
    // Add the node after its children have been processed not before.

    return nodes;
}

To get exact Order:
And also one more thing if you need to maintain insertion order of nodes U can use LinkedHashSet since hashSet does not maintain.
